# Using different dbs on production and test environment

Tags: python, github, configuration, travis-ci, configuration-files

I want to use a test db on my test environment, and the production db on production environment in my Python application.

How should I handle routing to two dbs? Should I have an untracked `config.yml` file that has the test db's connection string on my test server, and the production db's connection string on production server?

I'm using `github` for version control and `travis ci` for deployment.

Comment: Yes - though I prefer more readable config files - your instance configuration should be separate from your app. And maybe in a different location that is typically used for your system. Linux especially likes to divide app and config.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take Linux environment for example. Often, the user level configuration of an application is placed under your home folder as a dot file. So what you can do is like this:

1. In your git repository, track a sample configure file, e.g., `config.sample.yaml`, and put the configuration structure here.
2. When deploying, either in test environment or production environment, you can copy and rename this file as a dot-file, e.g., `$HOME/.{app}.config.yaml`. Then in your application, you can read this file.

If you are developing an python package, you can make the file copy operation done in the setup.py. There are some advantages:

1. You can always track the structure changes of your configuration file.
2. Separate configuration between test and production enviroment.
3. More secure, you do not need to code your import db connection information in the public file.

Hope this would be helpful.